# How to get the duration from start_date and end_date in Django?

Tags: python, datetime

These two variables calculates and stores the date and time:

```
start_date = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
end_date = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
```

I want to calculate the duration: I simply did:
duration = start_date - end_date

It returns the `datetime.timedelta datatype` like this:

```
datetime.timedelta(-1, 86393, 797032)
```

I want to show the duration. If the duration is 15 minutes, I want to show 15 minutes, if it's 60 I want to show 1 hour and so. How can I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply print it:

```
>>> d = datetime.timedelta(-1, 86393, 797032)
>>> d
datetime.timedelta(-1, 86393, 797032)
>>> print(d)
-1 day, 23:59:53.797032
```

Or, for more fine-grained control:

```
>>> d.days
-1
>>> hours, remainder = divmod(d.seconds, 3600)
>>> minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
>>> d.days,hours,minutes,seconds
(-1, 23, 59, 53)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to insert that duration to the database so that's not proper way for me. Also, I want to get secs, mins and hours not -1 day and something like that.